# Choppy Video on Inspiron 6000

Tags: windows-xp, video, dell-inspiron

I have an Inspiron 6000. I recently had to reformat the hard drive and reinstall Windows XP. I now notice my video is choppy. I have an integrated grapics card rather than and ATI Radeon 300 card. I have what I believe is the proper chipset installed. Any suggestions on how to get my graphics running smoothly as it was before the reinstallation?

Answer (score 1):

Did you make sure to install *both* the [chipset](http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/format.aspx?c=us&cs=19&l=en&s=dhs&deviceid=1134&libid=27&releaseid=R114079&vercnt=2&formatcnt=0&SystemID=INS_PNT_6000&servicetag=&os=WW1&osl=en&catid=-1&dateid=-1&typeid=-1&formatid=-1&impid=-1&checkFormat=true) and the [integrated video driver](http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/download.aspx?c=us&cs=19&l=en&s=dhs&releaseid=R128346&SystemID=INS_PNT_6000&servicetag=&os=WW1&osl=en&deviceid=3526&devlib=0&typecnt=0&vercnt=5&catid=-1&impid=-1&formatcnt=0&libid=6&typeid=-1&dateid=-1&formatid=-1&source=-1&fileid=170751)?

Comment: Thanks for the response, Kyle. Yes; I did install both the chipset and the video driver from Intel. Video still very choppy. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @Bruce Do you have any other info??? All I was able to get from the above question was that you think you installed the video driver, but your not sure, and you referred to it as the chip set. Has anything else changed on the computer? Are the other drivers installed properly? Have you tried running driver sweeper in safe mode and a reinstall of the video drivers?